# Does Jupyter Lab Not Support Match-Case Yet?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am working in Jupyter right now and I have just installed Python 3.10 on my local system. I was trying to implement a match-case in my Jupyter Notebook, but it does not seem to recognize this statement yet. Perhaps I am missing something, but how can I enable this feature?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your jupyter notebook is also using `3.10`? You can do that by checking the `sys.version` within your notebook

Comment: I am not sure what happened, I just did a hard reboot of the computer and we're working now. At first I was thrown off because there is no syntax highlighting for match-case like there is for if-else, but then I realized it was just not working. Seems to be okay now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if you are actually running on python 3.10 as follows:

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

Comment: Just curious, but any reason why you recommend this over `sys.version`?

Comment: @mortz you are right, that's maybe even bettter, but they both answer the question if OP is actually using python 3.10

Comment: When I ran it from within VS Code, I did get 3.10.0. Strange.